# Camel ftp consumer ignores idempotent file repository on start

Tags: apache-camel

I have created a route that consumes from ftp:

```
private RouteDefinition ftpRouteOcs() {
    IdempotentRepository<String> fileRep = FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(new File("./downLoadedOcs"), A_MILLION, TEN_MB);
    // from endpoint
    FtpEndpoint<?> ftpEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint(config.ftpUrlOcs(), FtpEndpoint.class);
    ftpEndpoint.setIdempotentKey("${file:name}");
    ftpEndpoint.setIdempotentRepository(fileRep);
    ftpEndpoint.getConfiguration().setBinary(true);
    //important!
    ftpEndpoint.getConfiguration().setStepwise(false);
    // no write or move operations - read only, set idempotent to true
    ftpEndpoint.setNoop(true);
    // only include files that match pattern
    ftpEndpoint.setInclude(OCS_FILE_FILTER_PATTERN);
    // fetch 1000 files in one poll...
    ftpEndpoint.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(FTP_MAX_FILES_PER_POLL);
    // but sort ALL files before...
    ftpEndpoint.setEagerMaxMessagesPerPoll(false);
    // ...by file name
    ftpEndpoint.setSortBy("file:name");
    // to endpoint
    FileEndpoint fileEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("file:" + config.ftpTargetOcs(), FileEndpoint.class);
    // mark finished downloads
    fileEndpoint.setDoneFileName("${file:name}.done");
    // ignore if exist
    fileEndpoint.setFileExist(GenericFileExist.Ignore);
    return from(ftpEndpoint).to(fileEndpoint).routeId(RouteIds.ftpOcs.name());
}
```

As you see i am using fileIdempotentRepository. The file is created fine and each file downloaded is added to the file - i get all related debug outputs. The problem is after a restart all files are downloaded again - the repository is ignored. The file is still there and on each run the file is updated - with the same data (create date keeps the same, change date is updated).
so what could be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Claus Ibsen answered on mailing list (http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-ftp-consumer-ignores-idempotent-file-repository-on-start-td5753615.html)

The solution is just add

```
fileRep.start();
```

So the repository must be started explicitly.